# How do I make a variable inside a plugin available for functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

In the following code exists inside a wordpress plugin. I would like to make $recipient_id available for a function inside functions.php. What would be the best way to do this.

```
class Private_Messages_Notifications {

...

public function new_message_notification( $message, $thread ) {

    ...

    $recipient_id = absint( $thread->get_recipient_id() );

    }

}
```

Comment: this would be helpful : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13707/variable-from-a-plugin-into-a-theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using **Sessions**:

Your Plugin PHP File...

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['variableName'] = $var_value;
```

ON Your Functions file

```
session_start();
$var_value = $_SESSION['variableName'];
```

---

> You can also pass the value using **cookies** if the variable doesn't
>   need to be secure...

Your Plugin PHP File...

```
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;
```

ON Your Functions file

```
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

---

> Using **Golabls**

Your Plugin PHP File

```
    function myValue(){
       global $varName;

       $varName = 'something';
    }

    add_action('wp_roles_init', 'myValue');
```

ON Your Functions File

```
global $varName;
echo $varName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `global` variable in your plugin Code:

```
class Private_Messages_Notifications {

...

public function new_message_notification( $message, $thread ) {
   global $recipient_id;
    ...

    $recipient_id = absint( $thread->get_recipient_id() );

    }

}
```

and use this in your functions.php file using

```
global  $recipient_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this solution, It works for me.

Your Plugin PHP File...

```
define('TEST_VAR','TEST_VAR_VALUES');
```

ON Your Functions File

```
$var = TEST_VAR;
```

Please let me know if you are facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class constant:

```
class Foo {
    const GREETING = 'Hello';
}

// somewhere else
echo Foo::GREETING;
```